# MySQL Replication fix after server shutdown/start

Tags: mysql, database, replication

Server1 is **Master**

Server2 is **Slave**

Both are in our AWS testing env and we stop them once done with our work. When start again, Master rotates/creates new binary log file but slave keep looking for same/existing one and replication stops. Right now, I'm manually repairing it by (slave):

```
stop slave; 
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='xx', MASTER_USER='xxx', MASTER_PASSWORD='xxx' , MASTER_LOG_FILE='new-mysql-bin.00000x',MASTER_LOG_POS=107;
start slave;
show slave status\G
```

and slave becomes good again.Mysql is 5.5.x on Ubuntu 12.04. Will appreciate any help in automating it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the slave should automatically see this from the master bin log, as the master also logs its binlog rotation. Example at the end of a master binlog:

```
#131107  5:28:48 server id 1  end_log_pos 1073742327    Xid = 6975863573
COMMIT/*!*/;
# at 1073742327
#131107  5:28:48 server id 1  end_log_pos 1073742372    Rotate to xxxxxx-bin.005504  pos: 4
DELIMITER ;
```

Check the end of your master binlogs if the rotation is logged there.